# Cocoa: Activating window:shouldPopUpDocumentPathMenu:?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nswindow

I have a document window with two NSWindowDelegate methods implemented in its NSDelegate:

- windowWillReturnUndoManager:
- window:shouldPopUpDocumentPathMenu:

The first one, windowWillReturnUndoManager, works as expected, which appears to indicate that the NSDelegate is set up correctly.

The second one, window:shouldPopUpDocumentPathMenu appears never to be called, even when command-clicking in the middle of the title bar of the window. A breakpoint set within it at "return TRUE;" never stops program operation.

Is there something else I need to do to get window:shouldPopUpDocumentPathMenu to be called?

As an alternative approach to this same issue, I downloaded the source code to TextEdit. It has the capability provided by window:shouldPopUpDocumentPathMenu—i.e. when you command-click in the title bar of a TextEdit window, you see the drop-down menu of the path to the file. But a search of the TextEdit source code for shouldPopUpDocumentPathMenu returns no results. Is window:shouldPopUpDocumentPathMenu: not required to get this functionality?

Thanks in advance to all for any info!

Best,

-Vik

Answer (score 1):

Found it! All I had to do was add:

```
 [myWindow setRepresentedURL:[self fileURL]];
```

... to my NSDocument's awakeFromNib method.

The document path popup now appears in the window title when the window name is command-clicked.